# how to get publish_stream permissions for post on facebook wall?

Tags: javascript, facebook, post

here is my connection:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: "348044465251207",
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
    var credentials = { uid: response.authResponse.userID, accessToken: response.authResponse.accessToken };
        SubmitLogin(credentials);
    }, { perms: 'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access' });




    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                //console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');

                mail = response.email;
                currentName = response.name;
                gender = response.gender;
                place = response.location;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Login/DetailsToDataBase",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { gender: gender, mail: mail, place: place },

                    success: function (data) {
                        generalScore = data;
                        div_element = document.getElementById("userScore");
                        div_element.innerHTML = "Your score is: " + generalScore;
                    }

                });

            });
        } //end if
        else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') { alert("user is not authorised"); }
        else { alert("user is not conntected to facebook"); }

    }, { scope: 'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access' });

    function SubmitLogin(credentials) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Login/FacebookLogin",
            type: "POST",
            data: credentials,
            error: function () {
                alert("error logging in to your facebook account.");
            },
            success: function () {
              //  alert("success log in facebook");
                //     window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    }

};

(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));
```

and this is the function to post on user facebook wall:

```
var params = {};
params['method'] = 'stream.publish';
params['message'] = currentName +' earn '+ score+ '$ in battelship!';
params['name'] = 'BattelShip';
params['description'] = 'let\'s see if you sucsses to break my highlight';
params['link'] = 'https://apps.facebook.com/348044465251207/?fb_source=search&ref=ts&fref=ts';
params['picture'] = 'http://www.israup.net/images/98d0808995e356818a0c016bc1a2a7cc.png';
params['caption'] = 'Try it by Yourself!';

FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    console.log('Error occured');
  } else {
    console.log('Published to stream - you might want to delete it now!');
  }
```

});

it post only on my wall (because i am the admin of the app), but for another users it says:
"The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

help me please!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) documentation again I think, you're using a parameter in part of your login flow 'perms' which was deprecated over a year ago in favour of 'scope' -

Check the examples that come with the SDK and read the login documentation, though the code might just work if you fix that error, i'd be wary of what other things have changed in the API since the example you're working from was written - you can check what permissions were granted to the access token you're using by calling /me/permissions with that access token